# NameError: name '' is not defined with multiple define functions

Tags: python

I just want to start off by saying I know this code is wrong, I'm just testing

this is meant to be a calculator, as you may be able to see from the code I am trying to make the number they end with e.g.
10 + 10 = 20, they will keep the number 20 and can carry on with 20, I want to keep repeating that option

Code:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

def main():
    operation = input("Do you want to(+,-,*,/):  ")
    if(operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
        print("That is an invalid operation")
    else:
        num1 = float(input("choose a number:  "))
        num2 = float(input("Choose another number:  "))
        if(operation == "+"):
            answer = (add(num1, num2))
            print(answer)
        elif(operation == "-"):
            answer = (sub(num1, num2))
            print(answer)
        elif(operation == "*"):
            answer = (mul(num1, num2))
            print(answer)
        elif(operation == "/"):
            answer = (div(num1, num2))
            print(answer)
        else:
            print("Syntax error!")
        def multiple(multiple):
             multiple =  input("would you like to carry the number(Y or N):  ")
            if(multiple == "Y" or multiple == "y"):
                carry = input("(+,-,*,/):  ")
                num3 = int(input("choose a number:  "))
                if(carry == "+"):
                    print(answer + num3)
                elif(carry == "-"):
                    print(answer - num3)
                elif(carry == "*"):
                    print(answer * num3)
                elif(carry == "/"):
                    print(answer / num3)
                else:
                    print("Syntax Error!")
    multiple = True
    while multiple == True:
        multiple()

choice = input("would you like multiple calculations? (Y or N):  ")
while(choice == "y" or choice == "Y"):
    main()
    multiple()
multiple()
main()

error message:

line 56, in <module>
    multiple()
NameError: name 'multiple' is not defined
```

p.s There may be some indentation errors in this as it pasted strange

Comment: The error message is not included in the code by the way

Comment: please take the time to fix the codes indentation, the scope of definition are very unclear

Comment: Indentation is still not valid

Comment: Without indentation correction it is very hard to tell what is what, but it seems that `multiple()` is defined inside `main()`, making it a local function to `main()`.

Comment: It is a good coding behavior to handle divide-by-zero :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the function `multiple` outside of the scope of the `main` function while it is only defined in it. Assuming that your indentation is as presented here, you need to move the definition of `multiple` outside of `main` so that it can be called.

Additionally, you're defining a variable named `multiple` which might create some problems. You should change it to something else.

Comment: I know it is inside the other define, but if I have it outside then it will not recognize the variables like answer, so I'm not really sure

Comment: then you should pass answer to the `multiple` function as well. That's a different problem though. There are many issues require fixing/adjusting in the code you posted :)

Comment: I could do that, however the answer was made by **num1** and **num2** being added, divided, multiplied or subtracted

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6a99596e843c30a87a5ce01527b4f3fb    


This is the exact code in my IDLE Program

Comment: Again, I'm sorry, but this is an entirely different problem and not the only one to deal with. You should address that in a different question. You're practically asking how to write code here.

Answer (score 0):

I optimized your code a little and fixed it. It works fine so take a look at it.

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

def main(carry):
    operation = input("Do you want to (+,-,*,/): ")
    if(operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
        print("That is an invalid operation")
    else:
        num1 = float(input("choose a number: "))
        if carry == None:
            num2 = float(input("Choose another number: "))
        else:
            num2 = carry
        if(operation == "+"):
            answer = add(num1, num2)
        elif(operation == "-"):
            answer = sub(num1, num2)
        elif(operation == "*"):
            answer = mul(num1, num2)
        elif(operation == "/"):
            answer = div(num1, num2)
        print(answer)
        return answer

if input("would you like multiple calculations? (Y or N): ") in ("y", "Y"):
    domultiple = True
else:
    domultiple = False

carry = None
while 1:
    carry = main(carry)
    if domultiple:
        if input("would you like to carry the number (Y or N): ") in ("n", "N"):
            break
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm am still very new to Python, I am 15 years old starting python in school for my GCSE, but I learn more at home and you have helped me out a lot.

Thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.